# having problems in importing from one file to another

Tags: python-3.x

For example :-Class B import some functions of Class A (Works fine). Problem arise when I tried to import some function of class B in class A.
file : a_class.py

```py
from b_class import B

class A:
    def fun(self):
        print("fun")

    def b(self):
        print("Function is to test")
        B().hello() #having issue
```

file : b_class.py

```py
from a_class import A

class B:
    def fun2(self):
        print("more fun")
        A().fun() # works fine

    def hello(self):
        print("want this function on class A")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = B()
    a.fun2()
    bo = A()
    bo.b()
```

Could someone please try to run this program and post the correct code in comment section because am working on one project and am having the same problem as I posted above.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. `Could someone please try […] and post the correct code in comment section` No. (Don't!) Good questions deserve useful *answers*. Comments are for reactions to the *post*, e.g. to the way a problem is *presented*.

Comment: I fail to recognize a question here... You presented some code and never said what is wrong with it... Are you getting an error? Wrong output? Please clarify the question. You can read more about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out : you have to put the `import`statement in a_class.py AFTER the class definition, like so:
file : a_class.py

```py
class A:
    def fun(self):
        print("fun")
    def b(self):
        print("Function is to test")
        B().hello() #having issue (not anymore)

from b_class import B
```

file : b_class.py

```py
from a_class import A

class B:
    def fun2(self):
        print("more fun")
        A().fun() # works fine
    def hello(self):
        print("want this function on class A")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = B()
    a.fun2()
    bo = A()
    bo.b()
```

Comment: `I worked it out` not quite: when an interpreter runs a program yielding the result desired, that does not even mean all source files involved are syntactically correct.

Comment: From [The Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports): *Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.*

Comment: (During an edit review, I've changed the string literal in the question body's `A.b()` to `"Function is to test"`, currently inconsistent with the code in this answer.)

Comment: @greybeard i know imports should go to the top, but in this case it is not possible (if it is, show us how !)

Comment: I am fully aware that I referred to a *style guide* where a *language reference* would be preferable - things I thought *should* work didn't when I tried them in my (t)rusty 3.5 environment. Then, there is the *design* angle: mutual dependencies are a headache.